# Trying to analyze .NET project with Sonar using Jenkins

Tags: .net, jenkins, sonarqube

I'm trying to analyze a .Net in sonar using Jenkins, but everything I build the project I get the error below:

**Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.command.CommandException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Ing1345-BalancedScoreCard/workspace/.sonar/SonarQube.CSharp.CodeAnalysis.Runner/SonarQube.CSharp.CodeAnalysis.Runner.exe": error=13, dennied permission**

I've read some post about the error and they say I should give execution permission to that folder, but it doesn't work.

Any idea of how I can solve this issue.

Jenkins Version:1.609.1 
Sonar Version: 5.1.1 
Maven version:3.3.3 
SonarQue Runner version:2.4
OS: Redhat

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 5):

The latest version (4.0) of C# plugin won't work on linux servers like your RedHat, due to the fact that it requires the analyzer machines to run on Windows, and the .NET Framework 4.5 to be installed. You can find more info on [official C# plugin page for Sonar](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+For+Non-TFS+2013+Users). Team responsible for plugin starting from version 3.4 droped Java based parser and they've written new version in C#.

Comment: thank you, after some research I saw that too, the plugin was updated so the C# project cant be analyzed anymore in the current platform, what I had to do was creating a slave machine on Windows so all those analysis run there from the Master jenkins machine

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to run your analysis for .Net on a Windows platform.  The Redhat Linux OS your Jenkins is running on cannot execute a Windows exe.